# How to access a method of a closure's parent object?

Tags: javascript, closures

I have defined a class named `MyClass` and I have defined two methods `myMethod1` and `myMethod2` for it:

```
function MyClass() {}
MyClass.prototype.myMethod1 = function() {...};
MyClass.prototype.myMethod2 = function() {...};
```

Inside `myMethod1`, I use jQuery and there's a callback closure defined there:

```
MyClass.prototype.myMethod2 = function() {
 $.jQuery({success: function(data) {
  this.myMethod2();
 }, ...});
}
```

Now the problem is that `this` no longer is referring to `MyClass`. The question is how can I refer to it? At the moment I have assigned it to a variable named `thisObj` and access it this way:

```
MyClass.prototype.myMethod2 = function() {
 var thisObj = this;
 $.jQuery({success: function(data) {
  thisObj.myMethod2();
 }, ...});
}
```

Is there a better way to access `MyClass.this` from the closure nested in `myMethod2`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you've used is often called the "that reference", because the name `that` is commonly used as a name for the copy of the `this` reference. See Crockford's talks on JavaScript for example.

Comment: Or `self`. I can't *stand* `that`, it's completely misleading. :-)

Comment: @T.J & @Daniel: Or maybe `parent` as in the closure's parent context? However as that's the convention to use `that` or `self`, then that's fine... :-)

Comment: Guys both of your answers deserve a check mark, however as I can't do that, I check mark the first answer, and up vote both of them.

Comment: @bytecode: Right thing to do going with the first right answer. :-) Re naming, both `self` and `that` are widely used. `self` has a long pedigree, it's the `this` of [Smalltalk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk), and Smalltalk is an ancestor of JavaScript's, indirectly through the language [Self](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self_programming_language). I've also seen `me`, presumably as an homage to Visual Basic.

Comment: @T.J: The thing is, when using `self`, `that`, or `me` inside the closure, it is not really referencing to `this` (i.e. the closure) anymore and it is actually referring to its parent context. On the other hand, if you define the reference as `parent`, in the place where you define it, it is not really the parent but `this` itself and we have some kind of paradox here! :) Having said that as I've seen `self` being used in a couple of other languages, and as you said in Smalltalk too, I am also mentally more comfortable with `self`.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is perfectly fine. Since you already have a closure there, may as well make use of it, that's absolutely fine.

But if you like, you can use [`jQuery.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) instead, like this:

```
MyClass.prototype.myMethod2 = function() {

    $.jQuery({success: jQuery.proxy(function(data) {
        this.myMethod2();
    }, this), ...});
}
```

Again, though, there's nothing wrong with your original solution. Using `proxy` can be helpful, though, when you want to reuse a function in lots of different places, or when you don't already have a closure and don't want to introduce one (perhaps because it would close over a lot of unrelated stuff). The good thing about `proxy` is that it creates a closure over a controlled set of stuff and not over the current scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a reference to this to the function, but your solution seems fine to me. You are just using the lexical scoping rules of Javascript so what is wrong?